# error shown Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in ccavenue payment getway integration in php

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open()  shown ccavenue payment getway integration in php.
we are using php NON_SEAMLESS_KIT.following error shown when we submit dataform.html file we already set the working-key,access id in ccavRequestHandler.php file but still showing error like `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in https://abc.in/get-way/Crypto.php:9`

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running PHP 7.2? mcrypt got deprecated in PHP 7.2, so you need to install it through PECL

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```